# Is it possible to move an array out of the main js file and import it in?

Tags: javascript

I have a js file that is mostly static. I do not change it at all except one array of values.

Is it possible to move that array out of the main js file and import it in?

Here is my js now:

sw.js:

```
// array that changes often
const assets = ['/','index.html','long','list','of','assets'];

// lot of code that rarely changes here
```

Here is what I want to do:

sw.js:

```
// array that changes often
const assets = require("assets.js");

// lot of code that rarely changes here
```

assets.js:

```
const assets = ['/','index.html','long','list','of','assets'];
```

And please let me know if I have to use ES5 or ES6 to do it.

**Related**:
Offline Service Worker
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps/Offline_Service_workers

Comment: Why would you keep such data inside your code?

Comment: Will an AJAX request to the file be sufficient?

Comment: @PM77-1 Read Offline Service Worker link. If the files don't change it's not a big deal but in my case they will change. That's the code from the guide for creating progressive web apps.

Comment: I don't know about service workers, but ES6 in general adds [modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules), which are almost certainly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes, it's possible. Make sure your declared `assets` variable is not inside the `function` so that you can access it globally.

*e.g*

```
<script src="assets.js"><script> //declare const assets = ['/','index.html','long','list','of','assets']; here
<script src="sw.js"><script> // you can access the variable *assets* from here.
```

Comment: I was thinking of something in the js itself but this should work too.

Comment: Yes, of course, this should work I had tried this before :)